# You avoided me a lot of troubles

Tags: meaning-in-context

Let’s say I lost my wallet on the street and someone has found it and just gave it back to me. I would like to thank this person and say he “avoided me a lot of troubles”, as in, he saved me from the hassle of notifying the bank, police, having to remake all my documents, etc.

Is it correct to say **“You avoided me X”**?

The phrase sounds a bit odd to me. I tried googling it, but I didn’t find any example usages.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I suppose it *could* be grammatically correct, but it's not something that I or anyone I'd know would say in everyday speech. Something like:

> "You have saved me a lot of trouble."

(i.e. "You have saved me (prevented me) from experiencing a lot of trouble (that is caused by losing my wallet, like replacing credit cards)).

is something that I know I'd say, if someone found my wallet.

Comment: A bit dated / stilted, perhaps, but alternatives include [*You've spared me a lot of / much grief.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22spared+me+much+grief%22)

Answer (score -3):

Another option might be "You let me avoid a lot of trouble" or "You let me avoid lots of trouble."

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.